# Batch: Create a list of folders and then copy multiple files/folders into all of them

Tags: list, batch-file, xcopy

I am a CAD manager in need of some help. I am no programmer, but I have a very basic understanding of DOS commands so I thought I could use XCOPY to do this, but I don't know how.

I have a folder, under which are hundreds of subfolders that change with time (each employee has one folder) so maintaining a manual listing (as I have been doing) is not easy.
I also have a _TEMPLATE subfolder that contains several files and folders.

I would like to copy the contents of the _TEMPLATE folder into all the other subfolders, overwriting all existing files and creating all non-existing folders.

From what I've seen with some searching in here it seems to pretty easy to accomplish these two tasks (to create the list of folders and to copy into a list of folders) but I'm just too dumb to understand how to combine the two into one file :)

**EDIT :**

Well, I've found a PowerShell script that does what I need perfectly. Since I managed to run the PowerShell I guess my problem is solved :D

```
$folder = Get-Childitem -name -exclude *.*,_TEMPLATE
foreach ($f in $folder)
    {xcopy "_TEMPLATE\*.*" "$f" /e /r /y }
```

Thanks for all the fish ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
cd /d "RootFolder=X:\folder\to\my data"
for /d %%a in (*) do xcopy "_TEMPLATE" "%%~fa" /sihrky
```

For xcopy options see `xcopy /?`,  to test the command without writing add option `/l`.

Comment: Okay, I've just tested this, and it asks me for Overwrite permissions for every folder, then runs through the list of folders several times and copies to each folder. I eventually just terminated the job. The asking is kinda tiring, but at least it works as I want. Thank you!

Comment: just add `/y` to the options list, see `xcopy /?`.

Comment: Oh noes! It actually copies endlessly. It finds all the subfolders of the subfolders and copies the contents of the TEMPLATE folder into there, then runs through the list again and finds all the new subfolders of the subfolders and copies into them and..... I now have nested folders 20 levels deep :(

Manual delete time :D

Comment: @ArniVidar tested it here: works normal. copies all files + subfolders & files from `_template` to all target folders in `RootFolder` and subfolders.

Comment: @ArniVidar I see now, I didn't understand you right :(( , I'm so sorry! You need the copies only one level deep, changed the code for this.